# sentry.CaptureException returning event id but logs not coming in Dashboard

Tags: go, sentry

I have a go program in file db/migration/db.go, inside which a db connection to PostgreSQL is getting created. I want a log into sentry if failed to establish a database connection.

The code looks like

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "flag"
    "fmt"

    "project-name/config"
    "github.com/getsentry/sentry-go"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/database/postgres"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/file"
)

type SentryError struct {
    LogMessage string
    Err        error
}

func (e SentryError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Error: %s", e.LogMessage)
}

func main() {
    cfg, err := config.Initialize()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
        return
    }

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf(
        "host=%s user=%s dbname=%s port=%s password=%s sslmode=disable",
        cfg.Postgres.Host,
        cfg.Postgres.Username,
        cfg.Postgres.Name,
        cfg.Postgres.Port,
        cfg.Postgres.Password,
    )

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        logMessage := fmt.Sprintf("failed to establish database connection: %v", err)
        sentryError := &SentryError{
            LogMessage: logMessage,
            Err:        err,
        }
        eventID := sentry.CaptureException(sentryError)
        fmt.Println(eventID) // 4f9270174607428c9e0a5ac85b130309
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

On executing this file in terminal, script prints event ID , but no log comes in sentry dashboard.

Solutions Tried :
1.Tried searching the event through URL sentry.io/ORGANISATION_SLUG/PROJECT_SLUG/events/EVENT_ID , but this gave me PAGE NOT FOUND ERROR, though all the parameters ORGANIZATION_SLUG , PROJECT_SLUG and EVENT_ID seems correct.

**Note:** I am passing project name as a project slug, because there was nothing like project slug in sentry project settings unlike organisation slug.

Also, Sentry has been already initialised inside config.Initialize() Method.

```
func InitSentry() error {
    sentryDsn := os.Getenv("SENTRY_DSN")
    if err := sentry.Init(sentry.ClientOptions{
        Dsn: sentryDsn,
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

2. Tried simply calling sentry.CaptureMessage here also, but getting the same issue.

Any other approach to debug such issue?

Comment: Sentry sends events asynchronously by default. Defer a call to [Flush](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/getsentry/sentry-go#Flush) in main to send any outstanding events before terminating the program.